# Django Bootstrap 4.0 Carousel Slider Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/

I'm following along with this and implementing it in Django.
There are no errors in the output console, so the static files (Bootstrap CSS + js) seem to be loading fine.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<!-- saved from url=(0052)https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.82.0">
    <title>Carousel Template · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/">

    

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'home/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template --><link href="{% static 'home/css/carousel.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <script data-dapp-detection="">!function(){let e=!1;function n(){if(!e){const n=document.createElement("meta");n.name="dapp-detected",document.head.appendChild(n),e=!0}}if(window.hasOwnProperty("ethereum")){if(window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion=!0,void 0===window.ethereum)return;n()}else{var t=window.ethereum;Object.defineProperty(window,"ethereum",{configurable:!0,enumerable:!1,set:function(e){window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion||n(),t=e},get:function(){if(!window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion){const e=arguments.callee;e&&e.caller&&e.caller.toString&&-1!==e.caller.toString().indexOf("getOwnPropertyNames")||n()}return t}})}}();</script></head>
  <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1002.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
    
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Carousel</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-label="Slide 1" aria-current="true"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2" class=""></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3" class=""></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-end">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide of this carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>



  <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

  <div class="container marketing">

    <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the three columns of text below the carousel. This is the first column.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Another exciting bit of representative placeholder content. This time, we've moved on to the second column.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>And lastly this, the third column of representative placeholder content.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->


    <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Some great placeholder content for the first featurette here. Imagine some exciting prose here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it’s that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Another featurette? Of course. More placeholder content here to give you an idea of how this layout would work with some actual real-world content in place.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">And yes, this is the last block of representative placeholder content. Again, not really intended to be actually read, simply here to give you a better view of what this would look like with some actual content. Your content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

  </div><!-- /.container -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-end"><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>© 2017–2021 Company, Inc. · <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Privacy</a> · <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</main>


    <script src="{% static 'home/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
  

</body></html>
```

After, I get the resulting image, however it's not moving, nor do the arrows do anything when they're selected.

[image]

Perhaps it's a problem with js. I can't seem to find a working fix on Stack, although this question seems like it's been asked a few times now.

EDIT: Hmmmm, not sure what I was doing but the navigation arrows are functioning now. But the slides do not change automatically after 3-5 seconds like on the example. How to fix this? I've really no idea what it's doing.

Comment: Try just adding the basic example from bootstrap first, perhaps in a separate template, then see if you can add django in to it. Then you atleast know there's nothing wrong with your bootstrap implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your edited que. ans:

You can use the `data-interval` attribute.

```
<div id="myCarousel" data-interval="5000" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
```

***Or***

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 5000    
});
```